# ¿Por que me sale:"[Error] ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]" en este programa?

Tags: c++

Hola ya he visto que ya habia preguntas sobre esto, pero no me quedo claro, porque aparecia en mi ejecutable.Tengan en cuenta que soy nuevo en este mundo.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
 int y;
 int x;
cout<<"elije una opcion"<< endl;
cin>> y ;
if ( y == "y")//linea 8
cout<< " has elegido si"<< endl; 
if ( y == "n")//linea 10
cout<<" has elegido no"<< endl;
else cout<<"no resconozco tu eleccion";
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que nada, bienvenido a c++ y a SOes.

Te explico lo que pienso que puede estar sucediendo,las variables **y** **x**, le estas asignando el tipo de dato **int**(enteros), este tipo de dato se usa para numeros. En el **if** lo estas comparando con un caracter (`char`) lo cual no tiene mucho sentido.

Puedes intentar de esta forma:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;



int main(){
    int opcion;

    cout<<"Elige una opcion (1 para X, 2 para Y)"<<endl;
    cin>>opcion;

    if(opcion == 1){
        cout<<"Eligio la opcion x.";
    }else if(opcion == 2){
        cout<<"Eligio la opcion y.";
    }else{
        cout<<"No escogio ninguna de las dos opciones";
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

o, si la quieres comparar con **x** letra que asigne el usuario:

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<conio.h>
    using namespace std;



    int main(){
        char l;

        cout<<"Elige una opcion (1 para X, 2 para Y)"<<endl;
        cin>>l;

        if(l == 'x'){
            cout<<"Eligio la opcion x.";
        }else if(l == 'y'){
            cout<<"Eligio la opcion y.";
        }else{
            cout<<"No escogio ninguna de las dos opciones";
        }

        getch();
        return 0;
    }
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Gracias, se agradece que haya gente que tenga la paciencia de explicarle estos temas a gente nueva, pero requiero de su paciencia una vez más, para que me responda la duda de cual es la diferencia entre "@" y  '@', que he visto que lo ha usado en determinadas situaciones.

Comment: si no me equivoco, es para entrecomillar algo dentro de una oración ya doblemente entrecomillada, ejemplo: "curso de 'c++' "